# A bag contains a number of marbles, 78 of which are red, 24 of which are blue, and the rest are green.

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics

If the probability of selecting a green marble is 1/3, what is the probability of selecting a red marble?

78+24=102

....Where do I go from here.......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the probability of selecting a green marble is $\frac13$, then the probability of selecting any marble that is **not green** is $1-\frac13 = \frac23$. There are $78+24=102$ marbles in the bag. If the probability of selecting any of them is $\frac23$, then these $102$ marbles must be $\frac23$ of all the marbles in the bag. So the bag must have $x$ marbles, where $x \cdot \frac23 = 102$. So $x = 102 \cdot \frac32 = 306/2 = 153$. So there are $153$ marbles in the bag. We have $78$ red marbles, so the probability of selecting a red marble is $\frac{78}{153}=\frac{26}{51} \approx 0.51$

Comment: Or 51/100 as a reduced fraction, correct?

Comment: Just Kidding, 26/51

Comment: I wrote $\frac{78}{153}=\frac{26}{51}$. Now, $\frac{26}{51} \neq \frac{51}{100}$. When I wrote $\approx 0.51$, the squiggly equals sign means *approximately*. The actual decimal expansion is $0.509803\ldots$, and I just said for simplicity that that's roughly $0.51$.

Comment: In reduced fraction form, it's $\frac{26}{51}$. That's the EXACT answer. (If you were to divide $26$ by $51$, you'll get $0.509\ldots$)

Comment: @FiguringItOut You're Welcome. You just need to make sure you understand the answer.